# GSON treat part of JSON as String

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to find a way to get GSON to read a part of a JSON object as a String, for example, for the following JSON code:

```
    {
      "id": "Foo",
      "damage": 53,
      "data": {
        "field1": "blabla",
        "field2": "bar",
        "field3": "Foobar"
      }
    }
```

I want the following output:

```
String id = "Foo"  
int damage = 53  
String data = "{\"field1\": \"blabla\", \"field2\": \"bar\", \"field3\": \"Foobar\"}"
```

The format of data doesn't really matter to me, as it will not be visible.

Comment: Please ignore the run code snippet buttons, I just don't know how to properly do code blocks on StackOverflow

Comment: [**LEARN**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). _Before_ you post.